# How to use useEffect with firebase's signin method properly?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

**Current code**

```js
const [uid, setUid] = React.useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!uid) {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        const { uid } = user;
        setUid(uid);
      } else {
        Authentication.signInAnonymously();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```js
import { ENV } from 'app/config/Env';
import firebase from 'firebase';

const { firebaseConfig } = ENV;

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default {
  signInAnonymously() {
    firebase.auth().signInAnonymously();
  },
};
```

---

If not signed in, users need to sign in with firebase's `signInAnonymously` method.

This is working but I'm not sure about if this code is right.

I would appreciate it if you could give me any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will result in multiple calls to `firebase.auth` every time the component is rendered, until the `uid` gets populated. While it might *work*, this doesn't seem desirable. It'd be better to run that block of code only once, the first time the component mounts:

```
const [uid, setUid] = React.useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      const { uid } = user;
      setUid(uid);
    } else {
      Authentication.signInAnonymously();
    }
  });
}, []);
// ^^  use an empty dependency array - this is very important
// to ensure the above block runs exactly once, when component mounts
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I need to learn more about ```useEffect```.  I was thinking that ```setUid(uid);```  would not work when signing in for the first time because the block runs only once when component mounts. I would appreciate it if you could explain about it.

Comment: When you set state, that state will exist forever, until the component gets unmounted or until that state variable changes again. So `setUid` once, on mount, will work just fine.

Comment: Thank you. But, ```Authentication.signInAnonymously();```, this part does not ```setUid```, right? So I was wondering why ```setUid``` is working :(

Comment: If you don't need to distinguish in state between Firebase not having loaded yet and the user being signed in anonymously, it's fine. If you *do* need to identify an anonymous logged in user, you'll want another state variable, like `isAnonUser`.

Comment: Thank you. So, every time ```setState``` happens, ```useEffect``` is called?

Comment: It depends on the dependency array. If the dependency array is empty, a `useEffect` will only run once, on mount. If state changes and a `useEffect` includes the changed state variable in its dependency array, the `useEffect` callback will run.

Comment: Thank you so much. Learned the dependency array is the key.